# High and low of First candle of the day to be recorded

Tags: pine-script

In intraday, I need put a BUY or SELL label on second candle whenever it crosses either High or Low of first candle. Need correct working codes. And I need this comparison to be done only once i.e whenever first candle High is broken or low is breached and not beyond that multiple times.

I tried to build this logic but it is firing multiple signals. I need to limit it to only once when the condition is met for the first time.

```
//@version=4
study("Close of first bar of a day", overlay=true)

isNewDay = time("D") != time("D")[1]
var firstBarHighValue = high
var firstBarLowValue = low

if isNewDay
    firstBarLowValue := low
    firstBarHighValue := high

buy  = close > firstBarHighValue and close>open
sell = close < firstBarLowValue and close<open

plotshape(buy,  title = "Buy",  text = 'Buy',  style = shape.labelup,   
location = location.belowbar, color= color.green, textcolor = 
color.white, transp = 0, size = size.large)

plotshape(sell, title = "Sell", text = 'Sell', style = 
shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color= color.red,   
textcolor = color.white, transp = 0, size = size.large)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
//@version=4
study("Close of first bar of a day", overlay=true)


isNewDay = time("D") != time("D")[1] 

var plotcond = false
var firstBarHighValue = high
var firstBarLowValue = low

if isNewDay
    firstBarLowValue := low
    firstBarHighValue := high
    plotcond := true


buy  = close > firstBarHighValue and close>open and plotcond
sell = close < firstBarLowValue and close<open and plotcond

if (buy or sell) and (not isNewDay)
    plotcond := false


plotshape(buy,  title = "Buy",  text = 'Buy',  style = shape.labelup,   location = location.belowbar, color= color.green, textcolor = color.white, transp = 0, size = size.large)
plotshape(sell, title = "Sell", text = 'Sell', style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color= color.red,   textcolor = color.white, transp = 0, size = size.large)
```

Comment: works well, Thank you for your guidance. I have one more detailed question on the same script. Is there anyway I can connect with you on trading view or other source ? my trading view user id is rvmohankumar

Comment: contacts in my profile